# Windows command line program to encode AVI to XVID

Tags: avi, video-conversion, xvid

I'm looking for a command line tool (preferably with no installation) which allows me to encode AVI to XVID (as MPEG4).

I know some solutions for Linux but can't find the same on Windows (XP).

Comment: You should try [WinFF](http://winff.org/). It uses ffmpeg for the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with WinFF, just go straight to [ffmpeg](http://hawkeye.arrozcru.org/).

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale 2 output.mp4
```

Adjust the `qscale` option (ranges from 1 to 31) to your needs. 1 means best quality, 31 worst.

Comment: Sounds good! Where can I find cmd line help / examples?

Comment: @Maciej: [Here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC20) and [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html).